# Multiple locations for NuGet Restore

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I know I can add different locations to a nuget.targets file, and I know NuGet will work by reading a file share.

Can I put a file share in a nuget.targets file however?

This is so my build server can use the nuget.targets file to pull the nupkg's.

I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
    <!-- Package sources used to restore packages. By default will used the registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config -->
        <PackageSource Include="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <PackageSource Include="//jcwinvm/Packages" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with backslashes:

```
<PackageSource Include="\\jcwinvm\Packages" />
```

Comment: @Jon Is it a remote folder?

Comment: Actually that did work, the nuspec file was incorrect. Thanks